# view stuck on `commitText` method of InputConnection

Tags: android, keyboard, inputconnection

I am committing text when user press key using the key code in `InputConnection`

but this method will hang the view and it will release after few milliseconds

```
if (getCurrentInputConnection() != null) {
    getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(String.valueOf((char) charCode), 1);
}
```

Is am I doing something wrong, or any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `commitText()` on each keypress.

Use

```
getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(mComposingText, 1);
```

for all keypress and commit composing text on `space` press.

To commit composing text use

```
getCurrentInputConnection().finishComposingText();
```

It was solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create an instance from `getCurrentInputConnection()`?

```
String txt = String.valueOf((char) charCode);
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
if (ic != null) {
    ic.commitText(txt , 1);
}
```